# Quick release lever for wheel is stuck

Tags: quick-release

So I was going to take my wheel off to replace my cassette but last night I gave it my all but could not get the quick release lever to disengaged. I've read to use a pipe for some more leverage but the lever is right next to the frame.

Should I try some PB blaster or anything like that one it? The other side seems to have those plastic caps vs a metal bolt (if that makes sense).

My guess is this wheel hasn't been removing in many years.

Comment: Leverage will get it, or snap something in the process.You are lifting the QR right?  not trying to rotate it as-is?

Comment: Correct, just trying to lift it. It's hard to get the leverage only cause it's right next to the frame. But I'm thinking maybe a large set of vice grips will work? Just worried about breaking it.

Comment: Find something that you can wrap around the quick release so that you can grip it better. Something like a piece or rope or sufficiently thick zip tie should be strong enough, yet still thin enough to slip behind it. Perhaps wear gloves so you don't have to worry about it cutting into your hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best bet with quick releases when they are hard to remove because of the frame in the way is to get a rag, place it against the frame and then use a long-handled screwdriver to pry it up. That works all the time in the bike-shop I work at. Good luck!

**EDIT**

I should actually say, if you have carbon fiber release levers, be VERY careful not to crack/crush it, otherwise that's gonna have to meet the wheelie bin.